# cmd prompt - Filter specific field from output using php

Tags: php

I executed command prompt in php. I got the expected result. In that output , I have all ip, host name, status in same network, but i want to get specific field from the output because i want machine name only. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hR9F.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Post you code here, so we can help you!
if you're newbie look here http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @SaranGaneshan - Please Edit your Question, don't post code in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the preg_match function,

```
$subject = '
192.168.0.1    WORKGROUP\A-PC    SHARING
192.168.0.2    WORKGROUP\A2-PC    SHARING
192.168.0.3    WORKGROUP\A3-PC    SHARING
192.168.0.1    WORKGROUP\A4-PC    SHARING
        ';

$pattern = '/([0-9.]+)\s+([\\w\\\\-]+)\s+(\w+)/m';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: it is working but i dont know how to filter the PC name only exactly.Please guide me

Comment: 分析字符串, 找规律, 然后用explode, preg_split, preg_match, 这些函数解析.

Comment: Now I have don't idea with namespace and use key word. I have done my basic add,edit,update function using mysqli-library. In that , I have used require_once ( 'file-name' ).  But instead of that, I would like to do the samething with 'use' keyword. So anybody guide me to do this asap.